# Injection using @Autowired not Working in @Webservice class

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap

i'm trying to inject services in Web service Class like this

```
package com.mobinets.web.nep.backend.soapControllers;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import com.mobinets.web.nep.backend.data.entity.Router;
import com.mobinets.web.nep.backend.data.entity.Version;
import com.mobinets.web.nep.backend.services.RouterService;
import com.mobinets.web.nep.backend.services.VersionService;

@Service
@WebService
public class RouterSoapService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{

    @Autowired
    private RouterService routerService;

    @Autowired
    private VersionService versionService;

    @WebMethod
    public String getRouter(@WebParam int objectId, @WebParam String versionName) {
    
        Version version = versionService.findByName(versionName);
        Router router = routerService.findByObjectIdAndVersion(objectId, version.getId());
        return router.getName();
        
    } 
}
```

I extended the class from `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` and add `@Service` annotation,

it keeps giving me null on `versionService` and `routerService`,

am I missing something ?

Comment: how did you create `RouterSoapService`?

Comment: i wrote it , and i generated wsdl from it

Comment: How is RouterSoapService created?

Comment: i create it man !

Comment: How does `RouterService` and `VersionService` class  look like? Do they have any annotation?

Comment: they have ```@Service``` annotation, however in the ```@PostConstruct``` method the services are not null , but in the ```getRouter()``` they are null

Answer (score 0):

Only reason I can think of would be if either of the services

- are missing one of the @Component stereotypes (you say they both have @Service
  so this should be fine) or
- if they rely on any other components which aren't autowired for example if
  either has a repository which has been instantiated with the new keyword
  they would be excluded from autowiring

Comment: I think the webService annotation has its own context which seperates it from the application context of the spring boot.
Maybe i need to create cxf file that have bean of these services and get them in the webService class , what do u think ?